# Trying to read an image and getting a null pointer exception

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to read an image and store it as an integer array so I can display it to the screen. I've no idea what is causing my code to return this null pointer exception and I was hoping someone could shed some light on it.

Here's the code for the load method:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TextureUI {

    private int width = 800, height = 600;
    public int[] pixels = new int[width*height];

    public void load(String path) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(TextureUI.class.getResource(path));
            int w = width;
            int h = height;
            image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and I'm using it here:

```
private Render ui;
private TextureUI texui;

public Screen(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
    ui = new Render(width, height);
            //Here is where my code is null pointing 
    texui.load("ui/hands.png"); // < That function call
    for (int i = 0; i < (width * height); i++) {
        ui.pixels[i] = texui.pixels[i];
    }
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on why it might be that this error is occurring?

Comment: you should post your stacktrace.

Comment: _Both_ answers from @leblma  and [at]Sotirios Delimanolis, below,  should be considered, as they each consist of a valid argument.

Answer (score 4):

Your texui attribute is null (not instanciated) and you try to call a method from it. You should instanciate your texui before calling its "load" method.

Put the following code in your Screen constructor:

```
texui = new TextureUI();
texui.load("ui/hands.png");
```

Comment: I tried this but it now the ImageIO.read function is returning an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: When you get an exception, you should post your stacktrace. I think you should look at Sotirios's answer, it will probably solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

If the path

```
ui/hands.png
```

is relative to the **root** of your classpath, then you should change it to

```
/ui/hands.png
```

If you provide a path without a leading `/` to the `Class#getResource(String)` method, it uses the package of the `Class` it's called on. For example, if `TextureUI` was in package `com.graphics`, then Java would look for the resource in

```
com/graphics/ui/hands.png
```

relative to the root of the classpath.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) explains it in more detail.